# Reversing a doubly-linked list with dummy nodes by using 'head.next' as a start point instead of 'head'

Tags: java, while-loop, doubly-linked-list

First and foremost, I have a working implementation of a `reverse()` method and I'm not looking for help on how to do it as it is a homework question. My problem is an error I ran into doing what I thought would save an iteration on my while loop by starting with the first real element in the list, rather than the `head` dummy node.

The working `reverse()` method code:

```
public void reverse() {
  Node<T> current = head;
  Node<T> temp = null;

  tail = head; 

  while(current != null) {

    temp = current.prev;
    current.prev = current.next; 
    current.next = temp; 
    current = current.prev;
  }

  head = temp.prev;
}
```

And an example of the program with which it belongs to running into the error:
https://ideone.com/KKUtMn

The change that breaks my program:

```
Node<T> current = head.next;
```

Making that change causes a `NullPointerException` on any calls to `addLast(x)` after a call to `reverse()` is made. The call to `reverse()` reverses the list without error or issue and I can call `addFirst(x)` just fine, but the first call to `addLast(x)` will throw the exception. I find it especially odd because the call to `addLast(x)` uses the `tail` dummy node to insert the element, but the only usage of `tail` in `reverse()` is assigning it prior to the loop and shouldn't be affected by whatever `current` gets referenced to.

The reason I thought I'd make the change is because that first iteration on `head` seemed useless when it just got reassigned to `temp.prev` after the while loop anyway. I didn't need the traversal offered by the loop either since I could simply point directly to the first non-dummy node from the start. I'm obviously wrong as the idea doesn't work, but I can't figure out the logic that makes that so.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you still set tail = head in the beginning. Since you never reverse the prev and next of your previous head, it will not HAVE a prev, only a next. Which causes the NullPointerException when you call addLast and he tries to get the prev of the tail ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could move to the end of the list

```
while(current.next != null){
    current = current.next;
```

if you are at the end, you start to swap the node's next reference...

```
current.next = curr.prev
```

and so on